# Android scroll to top next replacing fragment in scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

this is my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space.small"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/space.medium">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/space.medium">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bla_bla_bla"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

it is a fragment inside my tab menu, when this tab will be create the relative layout will be replaced by a variable number of elements:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.my_relative_layout, myListFragment).commit();
mHolder.scrollView.scrollTo(0,0); //not work
```

But my fragment doesn't scroll to top, it works only with a delay like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         mHolder.scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
     }
}, 100);
```

How can I do that in a right way? I won't use a delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to

```
"RelativeLayout"
```